# Multiple Unpacking Assignment in Python when you don't know the sequence length

Tags: python, variable-assignment

The textbook examples of multiple unpacking assignment are something like:

```
import numpy as NP
M = NP.arange(5)
a, b, c, d, e = M
# so of course, a = 0, b = 1, etc.

M = NP.arange(20).reshape(5, 4)     # numpy 5x4 array
a, b, c, d, e = M
# here, a = M[0,:], b = M[1,:], etc. (ie, a single row of M is assigned each to a through e)
```

(My question is not `numpy` specific. Indeed, I would prefer a pure Python solution.)

For the piece of code I'm looking at now, I see two complications on that straightforward scenario:

- I usually won't know the shape of M; and
- I want to unpack a certain number of
  items (definitely less than all items), and
  I want to put the remainder into a **single**
  container

So back to the 5x4 array above, what I would very much like to do is  assign the first three rows of M to a, b, and c respectively (exactly as above), and the **rest of the rows** (I have no idea how many there will be, just some positive integer) to a single container, `all_the_rest = []`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Python 3.x can do this easily:

```
a, b, *c = someseq
```

Python 2.x needs a bit more work:

```
(a, b), c = someseq[:2], someseq[2:]
```

Comment: What is the PEP that added this?

Comment: @geckos: [PEP 3132: Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). It's been around from the moment the 3.x line came out, starting back in 3.0. A related change [PEP 448: Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) allowed *constructing* types using the unpacking sequence, e.g. `{**d1, **d2}` to make a new `dict` literal equivalent to typing the key/value pairs from `d1` followed by the pairs from `d2`, or `['a', 'b', 'c', *range(10), 'd', 'e', 'f']` for putting `0`-`9` in the middle of a new `list` bookended by the letters.

Comment: I finally fixed an annoying error with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Syntax for this is added to Python 3

```
>>> # Python 3.x only
>>> a, b, *c = range(10)
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> c
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

but no similar solution exists in Python 2.

You can of course do

```
>>> s = range(10)
>>> s
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> (a, b, c), rest = s[0:3], s[3:]
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> c
2
>>> rest
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

or other similar solutions.

Comment: There is a python 2 solution (see the other answer) - hence the downvote.

Comment: Agreed - but it is confusing when you state there is no similar solution in Python 2 - I would suggest that there is a similar solution in Python 2, but the syntax is diffierent and it is slightly less "automatic".