# What do ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) mean in a function call?

Tags: python, syntax, parameter-passing, iterable-unpacking, argument-unpacking

In code like `zip(*x)` or `f(**k)`, what do the `*` and `**` respectively mean? How does Python implement that behaviour, and what are the performance implications?

---

<sub>See also: [Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727). Please use that one to close questions where OP needs to use `*` on an argument and doesn't know it exists. Similarly, use [Converting Python dict to kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710391) for the case of using `**`.</sub>

<sub>See [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901) for the complementary question about parameters.</sub>

Comment: addendum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141504/name-this-python-ruby-language-construct-using-array-values-to-satisfy-function

Comment: I think this should be phrased as the "* function call syntax".  They aren't operators, though it will get confusing as there *is* a `*` and `**` operator that have nothing to do with this syntax.

Comment: @Ian Bicking: you are full right, * and ** in argument list are pure syntax (tokens).

Comment: Note: For [PEP 448: Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) specific stuff (e.g. `[*a, b, *c]` or `{**d1, **d2}`), you'll want to read [asterisk in tuple, list and set definitions, double asterisk in dict definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36980992/364696), which is specific to the use *outside* of function calls and function definitions. For the earlier [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), see [Multiple Unpacking Assignment in Python when you don't know the sequence length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2531776/364696).

Answer (score 1193, accepted):

A single star `*` unpacks a sequence or collection into positional arguments. Suppose we have

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

values = (1, 2)
```

Using the `*` unpacking operator, we can write `s = add(*values)`, which will be equivalent to writing `s = add(1, 2)`.

The double star `**` does the same thing for a dictionary, providing values for named arguments:

```
values = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
s = add(**values) # equivalent to add(a=1, b=2)
```

Both operators can be used for the same function call. For example, given:

```
def sum(a, b, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

values1 = (1, 2)
values2 = { 'c': 10, 'd': 15 }
```

then `s = add(*values1, **values2)` is equivalent to `s = sum(1, 2, c=10, d=15)`.

See also the [relevant section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) of the tutorial in the Python documentation.

---

Similarly, `*` and `**` can be used for parameters. Using `*` allows a function to accept any number of positional arguments, which will be collected into a single parameter:

```
def add(*values):
    s = 0
    for v in values:
        s = s + v
    return s
```

Now when the function is called like `s = add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, `values` will be the tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` (which, of course, produces the result `15`).

Similarly, a parameter marked with `**` will receive a `dict`:

```
def get_a(**values):
    return values['a']

s = get_a(a=1, b=2)      # returns 1
```

this allows for specifying a large number of optional parameters without having to declare them.

Again, both can be combined:

```
def add(*values, **options):
    s = 0
    for i in values:
        s = s + i
    if "neg" in options:
        if options["neg"]:
            s = -s
    return s
        
s = add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)            # returns 15
s = add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=True)  # returns -15
s = add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=False) # returns 15
```

Comment: why would you need this, couldn't the function just iterate over the supplied list without it being expanded?

Comment: Sure, but then you would have to call it: `s = sum((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))` or `s = sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, the `*values` option makes the call look like it takes a number of arguments, but they're packed up into a collection for the function code.

Comment: Here's the real benefit: you can write functions that wouldn't otherwise be possible if you need to have a variable number of arguments. For example, C's printf function, which has 1+n arguments, is tricky to write as an exercise for any beginning programmer. In Python, a beginner can write def printf(string_template, *args) and move on.

Comment: To give some motivation coming from a C background, the \* acts in an analogous way as the \* operator in C, in that it 'dereferences' the variable.  In python context, this means essentially 'removing the outer braces' of arrays or dictionaries.

Comment: What happens if you (accidentally perhaps :p) unpack a dictionary with only one * instead of two? It seems to do something, it seems like a tuple comes out, but it is not so obvious what it is. (edit: ok I think the answer is that it just unpacks the keys, the values are discarded)

Comment: The last example implies that * and ** are not only doing the unpacking but also packing! See this excellent page https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/500/advanced-python-features#unpacking

Comment: @BenFarmer Yes; Python's `dict`s are iterable, and iterating over them yields the keys. So it is the same as if `.keys()` had been called on the dict first.

Answer (score 30):

In a function call, the single star turns a list into separate arguments (e.g. `zip(*x)` is the same as `zip(x1, x2, x3)` given `x=[x1,x2,x3]`) and the double star turns a dictionary into separate keyword arguments (e.g. `f(**k)` is the same as `f(x=my_x, y=my_y)` given `k = {'x':my_x, 'y':my_y}`.

In a function definition, it's the other way around: the single star turns an arbitrary number of arguments into a list, and the double start turns an arbitrary number of keyword arguments into a dictionary. E.g. `def foo(*x)` means "foo takes an arbitrary number of arguments and they will be accessible through `x` (i.e. if the user calls `foo(1,2,3)`, `x` will be `(1, 2, 3)`)" and `def bar(**k)` means "bar takes an arbitrary number of keyword arguments and they will be accessible through `k` (i.e. if the user calls `bar(x=42, y=23)`, `k` will be `{'x': 42, 'y': 23}`)".

Answer (score 24):

I find this particularly useful for storing arguments for a function call.

For example, suppose I have some unit tests for a function 'add':

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

tests = { (1,4):5, (0, 0):0, (-1, 3):3 }

for test, result in tests.items():
    print('test: adding', test, '==', result, '---', add(*test) == result)
```

There is no other way to call add, other than manually doing something like `add(test[0], test[1])`, which is ugly. Also, if there are a variable number of variables, the code could get pretty ugly with all the if-statements you would need.

Another place this is useful is for defining Factory objects (objects that create objects for you).
Suppose you have some class Factory, that makes Car objects and returns them.
You could make it so that `myFactory.make_car('red', 'bmw', '335ix')` creates `Car('red', 'bmw', '335ix')`, then returns it.

```py
def make_car(*args):
    return Car(*args)
```

This is also useful when you want to call the constructor of a superclass.

Comment: I like your examples. But, I think -1 + 3 == 2.

Comment: I intentionally put something in there that would fail :)

Answer (score 20):

It is called the extended call syntax. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html):

> If the syntax *expression  appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to a sequence. Elements from this sequence are treated as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are positional arguments x1,..., xN, and expression  evaluates to a sequence y1, ..., yM, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional arguments x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM.

and:

> If the syntax **expression  appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to a mapping, the contents of which are treated as additional keyword arguments. In the case of a keyword appearing in both expression and as an explicit keyword argument, a TypeError  exception is raised.

Comment: Just adding a footnote to the textbook answer - before syntactical support arrived, the same functionality was achieved with the built-in `apply()` function

Answer (score 0):

It is also useful when defining a dictionary that may have many keys with the same value.  For Example,

```
d = {'a':'r1', 'b':'r1','c':'r1','d':'r2'}
```

can be written,

```
d = {**dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c'],'r1'),'d':'r2'}
```