# Python : extract from list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list of lists and need to *extract* each item; to ultimately write their Cartesian product.

```
from itertools import product

b = {}
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], ['a', 'b']]

for i, v in enumerate(a):
  b[i] = v

#These don't work because we are feeding a single list to product
print list(product(x for x in a)) # [([1, 2],), ([3, 4],), (['a', 'b'],)]
print list(product(b.values())) # [([1, 2],), ([3, 4],), (['a', 'b'],)]
```

The `product` works correctly if I am able to get this :

```
print list(product([1, 2], [3, 4], ['a', 'b']))
[(1, 3, 'a'), (1, 3, 'b'), (1, 4, 'a'), (1, 4, 'b'), (2, 3, 'a'), (2, 3, 'b'), (2, 4, 'a'), (2, 4, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack `a` into `itertools.product` using `*` . Example -

```
print list(product(*a))
```

Unpacking would send each element of `a` as a separate argument into `product` , instead of a single list (just as - `list(product([1, 2], [3, 4], ['a', 'b']))` ).

Demo -

```
>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], ['a', 'b']]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> print(list(product(*a)))
[(1, 3, 'a'), (1, 3, 'b'), (1, 4, 'a'), (1, 4, 'b'), (2, 3, 'a'), (2, 3, 'b'), (2, 4, 'a'), (2, 4, 'b')]
```

Comment: Neat. I have seen the `*` operator many times. Does it do a similar job everywhere ?

Comment: In function calls (like the above one) yes. But when you use it in function definition it is different. Then it means any amount of positional arguments (and all those positional arguments are then put into the list with the name you used after `*` ).

Comment: Yes, there it means you wish to allow arbitrary number of arguments. Correct ?

Comment: Also, I believe in Python 3.x , you have multiple unpacking assignment where `*` is used - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531776/multiple-unpacking-assignment-in-python-when-you-dont-know-the-sequence-length .

Comment: Yes, you are correct.