# Is there something like pointer in Python

Tags: python, list, pointers, split

I want to understand the below code snippet from Python :

```
name, *line=input().split()
scores=list(map(float, line))
```

I understand `input()`, `split()`, `map` functions. I would like someone to explain me how the assignment `name, *line` work here and then how variable `line` is used in subsequent expression.

Comment: The `*` has nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: @user2357112 : So can you please elaborate concept is it .

Comment: `str.split` could produce more than one value. `name, *line = input().split()` unpacks the first value into `name` and the rest into `line`.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: @PeterWood so would `line` be an array, or automatically rejoined?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531776/multiple-unpacking-assignment-in-python-when-you-dont-know-the-sequence-length?rq=1

Comment: @Fallenreaper try it (c: It's a `list`.

Comment: @PeterWood yeah, it is.  That's neat.  Sometimes I learn more just from reading comments.

Comment: @PeterWood : Can we have multiple such variables in a single expression.