# Star expressions in Python not working

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am working on star expressions in python But I was getting a error.

```
>>> record = ('Dave', 'dave@example.com', '773-555-1212', '847-555-1212')
>>> name, email, *phone_numbers = record
```

The error I was getting is invalid syntax. I was working in command prompt

Comment: What version of Python are you using? You've also using `record` and then `user_record`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Unpacking Assignment in Python when you don't know the sequence length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531776/multiple-unpacking-assignment-in-python-when-you-dont-know-the-sequence-length); given that, you weren't using Python 3 as you thought you were. See also: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: Where does `user_record` come from?

Answer (score 1):

That syntax doesn't work in Python 2. Here's a Python 2 equivalent:

```
[name], [email], phone_numbers = record[0:1], record[1:2], record[2:]
```